# Найти проверочные слова

Tags: орфография, проверочные-слова, безударные-гласные

Как проверить слова "калачи" и "горячи"?

Answer (score 2):

Гласные в первом предударном слоге: калАч, горЯч. Гласные во втором предударном слоге проверяются в словарном порядке.

Answer (score 0):

Многие непроверяемые корневые гласные можно проверить по этимологическому словарю: калач - от коло - круг, родственники:колесо, кольцо, около - окольный, чередование ОЛО/ЛА

Горячий - дальние родственники:гореть, гоький - тот, который жжёт.

Не доверяете Шанскому? У него коло - круг (общеслав.)

Comment: >Многие непроверяемые корневые гласные можно проверить по этимологическому словарю: калач - от коло  
  
Не факт, однако.